# Regex parsing of ASP.NET tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a program to parse various file formats with a goal to find localizable strings (GetText pretty much). I'm looking for a regex that would get "TEXT TO TRANSLATE" from within specific opening and closing tag. I had a working regex but the following example broke it, thanks to the IsVisible call.

```
<mw:Translate runat="server" Visible='<%# IsVisible() %>'>
TEXT TO TRANSLATE
</mw:Translate>
```

This is what I have so far but got stuck with it...any help? I have described my wrongly regexxed intentions in //comments...

```
(?s)                   //multiline flag

\<mw\:Translate        //opening <mw:Translate> tag

(?:(?![^"']+\s*\>)+)   //match anything but > preceeded by " or ' 
                       //with any whitespace after it
(?:["']+\s*)\>         //match > preceeded by " or ' with any 
                       //whitespace after it

\s*                    //match any whitespace 
                       //(for trimming any whitespace around the text)
(?<text>.*?)           //capturing group for the localizable text
\s*                    //match any whitespace 

\</mw\:Translate\>     //match closing tag
```

The problem I have is probably in the opening tag...I'm trying to match the closing bracket > only when it is preceeded by " or ' with no or any whitespace after that...because otherwise it's either something like %> or it's not a valid ASP.NET

EDIT 1: **Please read the question before coming to conclusions. This is not HTML but ASP.NET which cannot be possibly parsed well with any HTML parsers. I'm also targeting something very specific.** Correction: people seem to agree it can be parsed with HtmlAgility pack but I don't really want to use it, because I don't really like to rely on an external lib for one simple use case.

EDIT 2: mw:Translate cannot be nested. It simply won't compile because of how the mw:Translate is programmed.

EDIT 3: Clarification of edits.

EDIT 4: Self closing mw:translate is not permitted

EDIT 5: HTML inside mw:Translate is as valid as any other text on ASP.NET page

EDIT 6: answered myself, the regex I'd need may be a bit more complicated (but not because of any relation with HTML), see below

Comment: thanks to regex you have broken your code...use an html parser

Comment: Dont use regex to parse html but [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: there must be a reason why Regex is strongly discouraged to process HTML tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Guys, ASP.NET is not an HTML. It's not even a XML.

Comment: @Motig html parsers like htmlagilitypack can parse almost anything remotely associated with html

Comment: I have no idea why should I use anything called "HtmlAgilityPack" to parse ASP.NET. What are the pitfalls here? There are very specific and concrete rules with this use case. I'm very well aware of the problems regarding using REGEX to HTML but this is simply not the case. If you think it is, you are free to make a fool of me in a valid answer.

Comment: @Motig all the best...

Answer (score 3):

Even if this is ASP.NET and not HTML you can use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse it.

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html); // html is the aspx document text
var translatableTextNodes = 
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[contains(., 'TEXT TO TRANSLATE')]");
foreach (var parent in translatableTextNodes)
    Console.WriteLine("Node:[{0}] Text:{1}",parent.Name, parent.InnerText);
```

Output with a sample page containing one of your server control containing `TEXT TO TRANSLATE`:

```
Node:[mw:translate] Text:
TEXT TO TRANSLATE
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you modifiy your regex.Here are some problems

- wont work if there are other tags inside(**next** to impossible to solve this problem with regex)
- asp.net can have self closing tags like `<a href=''/>`

---

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

You can use this code to retrieve it using `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);

var itemList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//Translate")//this xpath selects all translate tag
                  .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                  .ToList();

//itemList now contain all the translate tags content
```

Comment: These tags cannot be nested. It won't compile. I agree I should have written that.

Comment: @Motig by nested tags i mean other tags like <b>,<i> not Translate

Comment: In that case, they are part of the text and are parsed as a text. <b> is no different from "asdf". Anything inside those tags is a string. If there's a closing tag anywhere, even as a part of any crazy invalid HTML, as long as it's a closing tag, it's the valid end of the text.

Comment: @Motig ok..if you want it..use this regex `(?s)<mw:Translate(.*?["']|\s*)\s*>(?<text>.*?)</mw:Translate>`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try matching the list of attributes, assuming an attribute is wrapped in quotes or single quotes.
This is *an assumption* that isn't correct for all HTML, but it may work for you:

```
<mw:Translate       #opening <mw:Translate> tag
# Match attributes
(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))?)*
\s*
>                   #match >
\s*
(?<text>.*?)        #capturing group for the localizable text
\s*                 #match any whitespace 
</mw:Translate>     #match closing tag
```

Working example: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=5834b4f1-095b-4af6-a0da-d1fe119778bc

Comment: wont work with nested Translate tags..sometimes there's no closing tag

Comment: @Anirudh - Is that a requirement?

Comment: OP confirmed there are no nested tags

Comment: what about `<mw:Translate someAttributesHere />`

Comment: @Jerry Its not about nested tags..but ending tags..asp.net can have self closing tags

Comment: @Anirudh - The OP had something that worked, and failed a specific case. The original pattern had `"\</mw\:Translate\> "`, so these tags are not self closing. That also makes some sense: The OP is translating text.

Comment: ASPX may also have inline C# code, server side tags that brake client side tags, etc (think about a `<ul>`, `<li><li>` and `</ul>` in repeater templates, for example). Trying to parse these as HTML is more dangerous than a regex, in my opinion. You need an ASPX parser.

Comment: why ASPX parser? D: Please, if there's something I'm missing (or something I didn't say), tell me! Because for me this is pretty straightforward without any pitfalls as someone said.

Comment: @Motig - Everyone is suggesting to parse HTML with an HTML parser. Makes sense. But this is not HTML. What about CSV? I'd use a CSV parser - not an HTML parser (that would be stupid). We're dealing with ASPX, so we need an ASPX parser, if such is available. I don't believe an HTML parser is useful with complicated ASPX, but it's possible I'm being pessimistic. (**tl;dr**: I'm agreeing with you)

Comment: @Motig - So, does this pattern work for you? It may have other limitation you didn't have before.

Comment: @Kobi: For what do you want an ASPX parser? ASP.NET follows the same rules as HTML, so if you don't want to treat special ASP.NET tags differently(like page directive etc.) you can simply use an available html-parser like `HtmlAgilityPack`. You can even detect sever controls with tricks like `Attributes.Contains("runat")`.

Comment: runat="server" is straigthforward but how would an html parser perform for ASP.NET attribute bindings? Just curious.

Comment: @Kobi: Good example. However, it can be parsed successfully with HtmlAgilityPack. Of course you are not able to loop table-rows since this document is not loaded at all. But if you would parse the final html document generated from ASP.NET you would be able to loop the rows.

Comment: @Tim - Look at the repeater at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemtemplate.aspx - you have a `<table>` that starts in `<HeaderTemplate>` and ends in `<FooterTemplate>`. This is valid ASPX, but not valid HTML. There are more examples, of course, like ASPX comments. If you want to be 100% sure you are right, you need to use the correct parser.